# Angular 15+, mat-selection-list event (ngModelChange) or (selectionChange) stuck until lost focus

Tags: angular, mat-list

I have this code HTML

```
<mat-selection-list #contactsList [(ngModel)]="selectedAssociation" (ngModelChange)="onAssociateSelectionChanged($event)" [multiple]=false hideSingleSelectionIndicator=true>
      <mat-list-option *ngFor="let contact of model_list?.list; index as i; first as isFirst" color="primary" [value]="contact" [selected]="isFirst" >
        <mat-icon matListItemIcon class="mat-list-item-icon">{{contactClassIcons[contact.contact_types_id!]}}</mat-icon>
        <div matListItemTitle class="profile-line-primary">
          {{contact.contact_typeclass_title}}
      </div>
      <div matListItemLine class="profile-line-secondary">
        {{contact.contact_info}}
    </div>
      </mat-list-option>
    </mat-selection-list>
```

and the component ts :
**correction, idNotify is not @Output()**

```
idNotify: IdNotify;
onAssociateSelectionChanged(selectedAssociationList:ProfileContact[] | ProfileAcademy[]){
  console.log('SelectedContact:',selectedAssociationList)
  let selectedAssociationModel : ProfileContact | ProfileAcademy = (selectedAssociationList.length == 0 && this.model_list!.list.length >0)? this.model_list?.list[0] : selectedAssociationList[0];
      this.id_notify = //send downstream to commands to process
        new IdNotify()  //<----**code stuck here**
    console.log('sending downstream ', selectedAssociationModel)
}
```

the id_notify is the downstream event notification to the child profile-contact-edit,

as follows

```
<profile-contact-edit [idNotify]="idNotify" "></profile-contact-edit>
```

and the ts for profile-contact-edit has a setter for idNotify as follows:

```
@Input() set idNotify(id: IdNotify) {
    console.log(`id   ${JSON.stringify(id)}  `) }
```

The behaviour works as expected in the inital setup, the child does receive the idNotify as expected.
after that, when I click on another list item in the parent list, the new list item selected and the event triggered correctly, but the code stuck at the line when I set the idNotify property. until I click anywhere outside the list, then the code continues on as expected and the child receives the change.
Note: I have tried

```
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let contact of model_list?.list"  [value]="contact" (click)="onAssociateSelectionChanged(contact.value)"  >
```

with same results, it stuck at the same spot until I click out side list.

So in short, the code stuck until the list loses focus, so the question is:
How can I make sure the code continues while the list still having the focus.

Answer (score 1):

I general an [Output](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) should be an EventEmitter

```
 @Output() idNotifyChange= new EventEmitter<IdNotify>();
```

It's used emit

```
   idNotifyChange.emit(new IdNotify())
```

And get it using binding event

```
<profile-contact-edit (idNotifyChange)="idNotify=$event" >
</profile-contact-edit>
```

Comment: EventEmitter is to communicate child to master , idNotify is the master to child communication. so it is simply the change can be cought by either getter property or the ngOnChanges() event, you can learn about that in this link [link](https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/how-to-detect-input-value-changes-in-angular-child-component/ ) looks like I did wrong edits to my question I will correct it sorry for the confusion